# Removing JDownloader

Tags: 11.10, jdownloader

I installed JDownloader via `jd_unix_0_9.sh`.  Now I want to uninstall it.  Can anyone tell me how?

I think there should be some option like `jd_unix_0_9 -remove` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you didn't add JD PPA, and want to manually remove it, delete this folder:

```
~/.jdownloader
```

Additionally remove also these files:

```
/usr/bin/jdownloader
/usr/share/applications/jdownloader.desktop
/usr/share/doc/jdownloader/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/jdownloader/copyright
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/jdownloader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/jdownloader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/jdownloader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/jdownloader.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/jdownloader.png
```

Comment: THX, it actually only located in my home folder. So, I just removed ~/jdownloader and ~/.jdownloader.

Comment: Then others come from PPA install, I guess. Don't know why you have `~/jdownloader` folder, but that's not important now that you removed unwanted program

Answer (score 2):

Dirty but efficient.
And yes I know the post is 2 years old. Well... I got here over Google so others will too.

```
sudo find / -iregex ".*jdownloader.*" -exec rm -R '{}' \;
```

Please be careful, you can do a lot of damage with this command!!!